# findByAttribute Magical Record order

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios6, magicalrecord

How can I use Magical Records? findByAttribute to get ordered rows?

like I want to do:

```
[Service findByAttribute: @"parent" withValue: sparent];
```

but order each row returned by name attribute.

How can I do this using Magical Record?

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is:

```
[Service findByAttribute:@"parent" 
               withValue:sparent 
              andOrderBy:@"name" 
               ascending:YES];
```

[Here is a link](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.h) to their header file where all the fetch methods are defined.